# Rethinkdb - PHP-RQL - Http api - filter response

Tags: php, rethinkdb, reql

I'm working through several tutorials and examples on Rethinkdb and converting them to PHP-RQL for my own learning.

I'm currently looking at http://www.infoworld.com/article/2975838/database/build-real-time-web-apps-with-rethinkdb.html and can't work out how to replicate this:

```
r.http("http://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json")("data")("children")("data").orderBy(r.desc("score")).limit(5).pluck("score", "title", "url")
```

Specifically, it's the initial filter ("("data")("children")("data")") which I'm struggling to recreate in PHP-RQL.

Any assistance would be appreciated please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those query terms are the `BRACKET` terms from ReQL, and in this case (because they are being called with a string), they are equivalent to the `GET_FIELD` term.  I haven't used the PHP client driver, but some docs for those terms are available [here](http://danielmewes.dnsalias.net/~daniel/php-rql-api/).

These have examples on usage, which appear to be equivalent:

> Example: What was Iron Man's first appearance in a comic?
>
> ```
> $ironMan = r\table('marvel')->get('IronMan');
> $ironMan('firstAppearance')->run($conn)
>
> r\table('marvel')->get('IronMan')->getField('firstAppearance')->run($conn)
> ```

Perhaps the `BRACKET` term can't be chained onto the query like most other terms.

Comment: Great - yes, thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. So the equivalent of my query is 
`$result = r\http("http://www.reddit.com/r/aww.json")
   ->getField('data')
   ->getField('children')
   ->getField('data')
   ->orderBy(r\asc('score'))
   ->limit(5)
   ->pluck(['name', 'score', 'url'])
   ->run($conn);`

Thanks for your help